# Hosting in a .Net Core 2.1 Windows Service on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, .net-core, service

I've followed the instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1 to the letter and my .Net Core 2.1 Windows Service works perfectly when I create and start the service on my Windows 10 Pro machine.

The problem arises when I deploy on to our Windows Server 2016 Datacenter OS. It creates the service as expected, but when I go to start the service I immediately get the following error:

**The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.**

To emphasize, the service instantly fails to start with the above error.

If I try to run the exe itself I get the following error:

**Error:
An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (TestService.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices', version: '2.1.1'
path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices.dll'**

I suspect the two error are interlinked somehow.

I'm fairly convinced that the code is not being hit in Program.Main as I've added logging in the first line of code to be ran but nothing happens. I've tried adding the ServicesPipeTimeout registry entry to extend the time given for the service to start but I still get an instant fail. I've ensured that the server has the required versions of .Net Core installed and they are:

```
Microsoft. NET Core 2.1.1 - Windows Server Hosting - v2.1.13007.0
Microsoft .NET Core Runtime - 2.1.1 (x64) - 2.1.1.26606
```

I've also ensured the IIS is enabled on the system.

I've been struggling with this for 2 days and cannot find the answers to resolve these issues anywhere.

Comment: This doesn't help, but why the combo of .net-core AND windows service? If your target is pure windows, I would stick to 'old' .net, since .net-core was made specifically to run on non-windows envrionments.

Comment: @Davesoft I noticed that it was possible so thought why not give it a go.  Its frustrating because it works perfectly on me local developer machine, just not on the server.

Comment: "thought why not give it a go"   the bestest reason! Try an older server perhaps, just in case there's some 2016 pickiness going on.

Comment: So how did you port the code to the target machine? You've just copied the binaries or something?

Comment: That article describes about Framework Dependent Deployment. What you can try right now is to use Self-Contained Deployment.

Comment: @mmaguire My idea is that you've probably haven't done the publishing part as it was prescribed in the article, which would've packed third-party dependencies in a single folder, that you were meant to copy on the target machine. check it out